# Using helm to define relative hostPath

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to use relative volume host path in kubernetes config.

Is it possible to get the working directory in helm?

Something like $(pwd), but inside helm templates.

Comment: A hostPath relative to what?

The best guess to what the volumes pwd is would probably be where the kubelet is run from. But I don't see why any hostPath volume relative to that would be useful? 

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @FrederikNS, relative to the directory, where "helm install" executes. Like it works with docker swarm.

Comment: `hostPath`s refer to a location on the Kubernetes node that your pod is running on, not the machine you run `helm` or `kubectl` from. If you want to mount a file into your pod, you will have to create a `ConfigMap`, and mount that into your pod. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume

Comment: @FrederikNS, good to know, thank you.

Comment: Except when you're running helm against docker-desktop locally, because in that case the node is the same as the machine you run helm from. Local development is the use case for wanting to resolve a local host path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view working directory by running for example:

`helm install . --dry-run --debug --set workingDirectory="${PWD}"`

It will print the working directory under `USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:` and `COMPUTED VALUES` in the last line.

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but it could be the good alternative, if what I want will not be possible. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Is there no way to resolve a relative path in the template itself?